# how do i make a calling bar in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have a simple sms interface written in javascript and every time i click on a call button, a calling bar will(something like a progress bar that never stops or status bar). i still have no code for it because im still a beginner..please help

i have here a link http://jsfiddle.net/XBppR/22/

```
function openPage()
{
if(some conditon)
opener.document.location = "http://www.google.com";
}
else{
// nothing, this else not required
}
}
```

this code is not working..don't mind this..for posting purposes only..

Comment: HTML5 progress tag: http://peter.sh/examples/?/html/meter-progress.html

Comment: describe your "call bar" a little more, an image would be nice

Comment: Mozilla also has some documentation on the [`progress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/progress) element.

Comment: @pitaj:it is similar when you are calling and waiting for someone to answer..something like that..

Comment: What? calling and waiting for someone to answer? on what phone?

Comment: @pitaj:yup, similar to progress bar that never stops..a running bar, a meter bar..it's kindalike that..please bear with me im jus a beginner..

Comment: like this: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/indeterChromeWin.png

Comment: @pitaj:yup but it's running of course...but i want 'dots' running if possible..u know wat i mean ryt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning:** The following answer contains jQuery

So what you need to do is make two images, a foreground image to set the style:
[image: Can't see it very well, but there are dots there, highlight it to see]
(Can't see it very well, put it on a black background)

And a background image to create an animation effect:

[image: bg image]

Next, you must superimpose the FG on the BG.

HTML:

```
<div class="callbar">
    <div class="callbarbg" style="width: 200px;"></div>
    <div class="callbarfg"></div> <!-- later elements have higher z-index -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.callbarbg {
    height: 20px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url("http://s9.postimage.org/4oij09p7j/sliding_Progress_Bar_BG.png");
    background-position:right top;
}
.callbarfg {
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("http://s9.postimage.org/bg8y34e73/sliding_Progress_Bar_FG.png");
}
.callbar {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Finally, you must move the background image in order to make the fade in/out animation in each dot:

JS:

```
window.setInterval(function(){ 
    var obj = $("parent of .callbar").find(".callbarbg"); 
    if(!obj.data("width"))
        obj.data("width", 200);
    var w = obj.data("width") + 3;
    obj.data("width", w).css("width", w);
    var h = w%200;
    if(h == 0 || h == 1 || h == 2){
        obj.data("width", 200);
    }
}, 33);
```

working jQuery jsFiddle with crude API: http://jsfiddle.net/pitaj/K25U8/6/

---

**EDIT:**

jQuery-free jsfiddle now up!

working jQuery-free jsFiddle with crude API: http://jsfiddle.net/pitaj/GpGE2/

Comment: I had some fun with that pressing start over and over xD. Great fiddle

Comment: oh it's nice but javascript only :(

Comment: @sircapsalot - It's a **crude** API

Comment: @ChristianBusaco - You get the idea though, right?

Comment: yup but im having difficulties converting jquery to js..i have a link here <http://2.s3.envato.com/files/2526201/index.html> please click the"other example 2" i can't get the code , it will not run, any help?

Comment: hey one more thing how can i post your code to my webpage?it seemslike it's not  working, i dnt know how to handle jquery..

Comment: @ChristianBusaco - See the edit to my post, I made a jQuery-free version of the jsfiddle